# Syntax error in code converted from bash to python

Tags: python, bash, syntax-error, converters

I am very novice to python. I have code in bash need to convert it to python, tired with converter but getting syntax error. Will be very helpful if someone help me in finding error !

Error :

```
File "cp_file.py", line 75
    print(myfilename.val)
  SyntaxError : Invalid Syntax
```

Will be very helpful if someone convert following bash code to python without or help me in finding error !

Bash Code :

```
grep " 200 " /var/log/ba/access.log |awk '{print $7}'|sort|uniq  > /tmp/read_log.txt

for i in $(cat /tmp/read_log.txt); do
        echo $i
        myfilename="$(echo ${i##*/})"
        echo $myfilename
        wget http://mydata.na.xyz/$i
        curl -X POST -d @$myfilename http://xyz.xyz/ba/$i
done
```

Python  Code :

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
import sys,os,subprocess
class Bash2Py(object):
  __slots__ = ["val"]
  def __init__(self, value=''):
    self.val = value
  def setValue(self, value=None):
    self.val = value
    return value

def GetVariable(name, local=locals()):
  if name in local:
    return local[name]
  if name in globals():
    return globals()[name]
  return None

def Make(name, local=locals()):
  ret = GetVariable(name, local)
  if ret is None:
    ret = Bash2Py(0)
    globals()[name] = ret
  return ret

def Str(value):
  if isinstance(value, list):
    return " ".join(value)
  if isinstance(value, basestring):
    return value
  return str(value)

def Array(value):
  if isinstance(value, list):
    return value
  if isinstance(value, basestring):
    return value.strip().split(' ')
  return [ value ]

_rc0 = _rcr1, _rcw1 = os.pipe()
if os.fork():
    os.close(_rcw1)
    os.dup2(_rcr1, 0)
    _rcr2, _rcw2 = os.pipe()
    if os.fork():
        os.close(_rcw2)
        os.dup2(_rcr2, 0)
        _rcr3, _rcw3 = os.pipe()
        if os.fork():
            os.close(_rcw3)
            os.dup2(_rcr3, 0)
            subprocess.call("uniq",shell=True,stdout=file("/tmp/read_log.txt",'wb'))

        else:
            os.close(_rcr3)
            os.dup2(_rcw3, 1)
            subprocess.call(["sort"],shell=True)
            sys.exit(0)

    else:
        os.close(_rcr2)
        os.dup2(_rcw2, 1)
        subprocess.call(["awk","{print $7}"],shell=True)
        sys.exit(0)

else:
    os.close(_rcr1)
    os.dup2(_rcw1, 1)
    subprocess.call(["grep","200","/var/log/ba/access.log"],shell=True)
    sys.exit(0)

for Make("i").val in Array(os.popen("cat /tmp/read_log.txt").read().rstrip("\n")):
    print(i.val)
    Make("myfilename").setValue(os.popen("echo "+str(i.val##*/)).read().rstrip("\n"))
    print(myfilename.val)
    subprocess.call(["wget","http://xyz.xyz/"+str(i.val)],shell=True)
    subprocess.call(["curl","-X","POST","-D","@"+str(myfilename.val),"http://xyz.xyz/ba/"+str(i.val)],shell=True)
```

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. You need to try to do it yourself, and then ask help when you have a problem with a **short** piece of code.

Comment: There is no way the conversion should look this ugly.

Comment: Among other things wrong with your code, `shell=True` causes all arguments other than the first to be ignored (the first argument is run as a script, other arguments are passed to that script, but in none of these cases does the string passed in the script position look at its other arguments).

Comment: Regarding help with finding the error, it would be easier if you included the actual error instead of just the location. But if this is just a one-off thing, I think you'd be better off converting manually.

Comment: @PauloAlmeida oops I missed error line now updated my question Thanks

Comment: @JamesZ  modified my questions hope so now it looks fine thanks for your feedback !

Comment: @COLDSPEED  modified my questions hope so now it looks fine thanks for your feedback !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That auto-generated Python code is horrible.  You'd be much better off sticking with Bash.  But best would be to actually migrate your code to Python using human understanding.  For example, take just this part:

```
grep " 200 " /var/log/ba/access.log | awk '{print $7}'|sort|uniq  > /tmp/read_log.txt
```

In Python that is something like:

```
with open('/var/log/ba/access.log') as infile, open('/tmp/read_log.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    results = set()
    for line in infile:
        if ' 200 ' in line:
            tokens = line.split()
            results.add(tokens[6]) # 7th token
    for result in sorted(results):
        print >>outfile, result
```

For the HTTP part, use the Python module [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/).  It's easy to use.  Quite possibly you won't need `outfile` anymore--you can just directly use `for result in sorted(results)` to make your HTTP requests.

Answer (score 1):

First never read lines of a file with for, use while instead. [See here why](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/24278/184398)

It's a very small script, is more easy rewrite in python than use your converter.

If are in hurry and really need the script in python you can use linux commands inside python, is not the best way but is more faster and easy for someone who don't know python

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(["curl","POST","-X", "YOUR_URL"], 
stdout=subprocess.PIPE,  shell=True) (output, err) = p.communicate()
```

Comment: but the file names which I want to post using curl is derived from '/var/log/ba/access.log'